# System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range. in WindowsPhone App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am Writing a **Windows Phone 8.1 App (WINRT).**

```
else if (GetProductByCategoryResultObject.Status == "1") //status is 1
                            {
                                //TODO:

                                //ProductsListingObject


                                ListView ProuctListView = new ListView();
                                ProductsListing ProductsListingObject = new ProductsListing();

                                for (int i = 0; i < GetProductByCategoryResultObject.Products.Count;i++ )
                                {

                                    ProductsListingObject.ProductsListingLabel.Text = GetProductByCategoryResultObject.Products[i].ProductName;

                                    if (GetProductByCategoryResultObject.Products[i].ProductThumbnail != null || GetProductByCategoryResultObject.Products[i].ProductThumbnail != "")
                                    {
                                        ProductsListingObject.ProductsListingImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(GetProductByCategoryResultObject.Products[i].ProductThumbnail,UriKind.Absolute));

                                    }

                                    ProuctListView.Items.Add(ProductsListingObject);

                                }

                                Grid GridObject = new Grid();
                                GridObject.Children.Add(ProuctListView);
                                (MainPagePivot.SelectedItem as PivotItem).Content = GridObject;
    }
```

If the **GetProductByCategoryResultObject.Products.Count** (Number of products) is 1, then application is running fine. but if the count is more than 1. Its giving me Error:
**{System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.**

Answer (score 0):

```
                ListView ProuctListView = new ListView();

                for (int i = 0; i < GetProductByCategoryResultObject.Products.Count;i++ )
                {
                    ProductsListing ProductsListingObject = new ProductsListing();

                    ProductsListingObject.ProductsListingLabel.Text = GetProductByCategoryResultObject.Products[i].ProductName;

                    if (GetProductByCategoryResultObject.Products[i].ProductThumbnail != null || GetProductByCategoryResultObject.Products[i].ProductThumbnail != "")
                    {
                        ProductsListingObject.ProductsListingImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(GetProductByCategoryResultObject.Products[i].ProductThumbnail,UriKind.Absolute));

                    }

                    ProuctListView.Items.Add(ProductsListingObject);

                }

                //Grid GridObject = new Grid();
                //GridObject.Children.Add(ProuctListView);
                (MainPagePivot.SelectedItem as PivotItem).Content = null;

                //(MainPagePivot.SelectedItem as PivotItem).Content = GridObject;
                (MainPagePivot.SelectedItem as PivotItem).Content = ProuctListView;
```